# Authorize Firestore call in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm using Firestore for my project and also Firebase Authentication for the Login part.I need to authorize my Firestore calls with the logged-in user because I'm checking some Rules on the DB side. Currently, I'm doing the authorization part manually by adding an authorization header to the API calls using Axios. But instead of that, I need to authorize my Firestore call

This is my sample code

```
await addDoc(collection(firestore, 'assign_workfaces'), {
            balcony: selectedBalcony,
            building: selectedBuilding,
            selectedWorkfaceMatrix: selectedWorkfaceMatrix,
            status: 'Pending',
            organization: {
                id: localStorage.getItem('OrganizationId'),
                organizationName: localStorage.getItem('OrganizationName')
            }
        });
```

This is what I have to do because the above part does not passing token

```
async assigneWorkFace(selectedWorkfaceMatrix,floorNumber,building,balcony) {
    let projectManagersList = []
    await axios.post('https://firestore.googleapis.com/v1/projects/*******/databases/(default)/documents/assign_workfaces', 
    {
        fields: { 
            organization: {
                mapValue: {
                    fields: {
                        id: { stringValue: localStorage.getItem('OrganizationId') },
                        organizationName: { stringValue:  localStorage.getItem('OrganizationName') }
                    }
                }
            },
            building: {
                mapValue: {
                    fields: {
                        id: { stringValue: building.id },
                        buildingName: { stringValue: building.buildingName },
                    }
                }
            },
            balcony: {
                mapValue: {
                    fields: {
                        id: { stringValue: balcony.id },
                        balconyCode: { stringValue: balcony.balconyCode }
                    }
                }
            }
        } 
      }, 
    {
        headers: {
          'Authorization': `Bearer ${authToken}` 
        }
    }
    ).then(res => { 
        // console.log(res.data) 
        projectManagersList = res.data
    })
    .catch(error => { 
        console.log(error) 
    })

    return projectManagersList;
  }
```

This is the rule I'm using on DB side

```
function isUser(userId) {
    return userId != null;
}
match /assign_workfaces/{assign_workface} {
   allow read, write : if isUser(request.auth.uid);
}
```

This is the firebase initialize part (Firebase 9.1.0)

```
const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "**************",
  authDomain: "**************",
  projectId: "**************",
  storageBucket: "**************",
  messagingSenderId: "**************",
  appId: "**************"
};

const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const firestore = getFirestore(app);
```

How can I pass the Authorization header with my first code part?

Answer (score 0):

I've only ever and only ever seen the bearer token passed through as part of the call the way you've shown

```
axios.post('/', body, headers: {'Authorization': `Bearer ${authToken}` })
```

I usually have a firebase function that verifys the token (as to remove that from being a client side thing), which you could then compare that data with database

You could alternatively do this within the react side too, checkout [the firebase docks for verifying ID tokens](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens#web)